# Como incluir automaticamente um arquivo, que não é uma classe, no composer?

Tags: php, composer

No composer, geralmente quando vamos configurar o autoload para arquivos que contenha classes, eu costumo fazer assim:

```
"autoload" : { 
   "psr-4" : { "WallaceMaxters\\Timer\\" : 'src/timer'}
}
```

O Composer automaticamente carregará o arquivo que tenha o mesmo nome da classe assim que a mesma for instanciada.

Porém agora eu tenho um arquivo chamado `functions.php` que possui algumas funções que desejo incluir nessa mesma biblioteca.

Como faço para o composer incluir um arquivo automáticamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você também pode incluir `arquivos` no Composer:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "files": ["src/minhaBiblioteca/functions.php"]
    }
}
```

Dessa forma, o Composer vai garantir que arquivos definidos como `files` sob a diretiva de `autoload` serão carregados automaticamente.

Referência

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files

Comment: Precisa atualizar o composer ou só adicionar o caminho do arquivo? Eu criei uma class mas não está achando a class.